# QGIS zoom in, zoom out, and pan tools cannot be toggled off

Tags: gis, qgis

When I select the Pan Map, zoom in, and zoom out tools  in the  QGIS toolbar (version 2.18.16), I cannot toggle it off after using it. In efforts to toggle a tool from the toolbar off after using it, I have tried clicking the tool again and pressing escape but none works. How do I toggle off a tool like pan or zoom in QGIS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

By default there is always one tool active, so if you want to stop zooming, click the pan tool again or select some other tool.